# How to find a word in a text file and delete the line containing the word and the next two lines?

Tags: batch-file, replace

I want to find a word in a text file using a batch file and then I want to remove that line containing the word and also delete some other lines below for example:

```
_italic_ or **bold**
put returns between paragraphs
indent code by 4 spaces
indent code by 4 spaces
_italic_ or **bold**2
```

so the result should be:

```
_italic_ or **bold**
_italic_ or **bold**2
```

Comment: Please give brief of efforts you have made for your problem. Provide chunk of code that you have tried or something like that. Refer this:http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I just can replace a word with another one so this is not useful here is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get the number of lines before the one that contain "returns"
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "returns" input.txt') do set /A "lines=%%a-1"

rem Open a code block to read from input.txt and write to output.txt
< input.txt (

   rem Read and write the first "lines" lines
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%lines%) do (
      set "line="
      set /P "line="
      echo(!line!
   )

   rem Omit the number of desired lines (3 in this example)
   for /L %%i in (1,1,3) do set /P "line="

   rem Copy the rest of lines
   findstr "^"

) > output.txt

rem Replace the original file by the new one
move /Y output.txt input.txt
```

Comment: As user @Mofi indicated in a (now deleted) comment, this solution just remove the last occurrence of the searched string. The code must be modified in order to delete the first or all occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this batch code:

```
@echo off
set skipline=2
set search=returns
set File=Input.txt
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in ("%File%") do (
    set linecount=1
    set skip=0
    For /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%b IN (`type "%%a" ^| find /V /N ""`) do (
        set a=%%b
        set a=!a:*]=!
        if "!a!" NEQ "" (
            set search=!a:%search%=!
            if "!search!" NEQ "!a!" set /a skip=%skipline%+!linecount!
        )
        if !linecount! GTR !skip! echo(!a!
        set /a linecount+=1

    )>>tmp
    move /Y "tmp" "%%a">Nul
)
EndLocal
exit
```

This is working with a file containing blank lines and multiple line.

Change **set skipline=2** for how many line to skip after find a word you search.

And for multiple files just change **set File=Input.txt**.

Example for file with extension **.txt** in current directory:

```
set File=*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batch code for this task working only for an input text file not containing empty lines as those lines are skipped by command **FOR**.

It removes **all** blocks with 3 lines whereby first line contains `returns`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "SkipLineCount=0"
set "OutputFile=OutputTextFile.txt"
del "%OutputFile%" 2>nul
for /F "usebackq eol=^ delims=" %%I in ("InputTextFile.txt") do (
    if !SkipLineCount! EQU 0 (
        set "Line=%%I"
        set "Line=!Line:returns=!"
        if "!Line!" NEQ "%%I" ( set "SkipLineCount=1" ) else echo(%%I>>"%OutputFile%"
    ) else (
        set /A SkipLineCount+=1
        if !SkipLineCount! EQU 3 set "SkipLineCount=0"
    )
)
move /Y "%OutputFile%" "InputTextFile.txt"
endlocal
```

This batch file processes each non empty line. Command **FOR** skips automatically all lines not containing any character.

Note 1: `eol=^` in line with command **FOR** is necessary to read in and output also lines just containing commas or semicolons which otherwise would be also ignored by command **FOR**.

The current line is assigned to variable `Line` if currently no lines should be skipped. Next all occurrences of the word `returns` are removed case-insensitive from the line if the line contains at least one `returns`.

The line is ignored if the string of variable `Line` is not equal after the string replace with unmodified line read from file because this means the line contains at least one `returns`.

Otherwise the line read from input file is appended to output file.

Note 2: `(` between `echo` and `%%I` is used here to output also input lines containing only 1 or more spaces or tabs as otherwise with a space instead of `(` the command **echo** would write for such a case its current state `OFF` into the output file instead of the spaces/tabs read from input file.

The next 2 lines after a line with at least one `returns` are also ignored for being copied to output file.

As last command the created output file with the 3 lines removed is moved over the input text file.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).